# jQuery UI Switch Tab After Function Done

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.0

```
    $('#uitab').tabs({
        show:function(event, ui){
        var lastOpenedPanel = $(this).data('lastOpenedPanel');
        if(!$(this).data('topPositionTab')){
            $(this).data('topPositionTab', $(ui.panel).position().top)
        }
            $(ui.panel).hide().fadeIn(500);
            if(lastOpenedPanel){/
                lastOpenedPanel
                    .toggleClass('ui-tabs-hide')
                    .css('position','absolute')
                    .css('top',$(this).data('topPositionTab') + 'px')
                    .fadeOut(500,function(){
                        $(this).css('position','');
                    });
            }
            $(this).data('lastOpenedPanel', $(ui.panel));
        }
    });
```

this is the jQ UI tabs code in head
then body looks:

```
<div id="uitabs">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#uitabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#uitabs-2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#uitabs-3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="uitabs-1">...</div>
    <div id="uitabs-2">...</div>
    <div id="uitabs-3">...</div>
</div>
```

and have a script inside #uitabs-1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
xxxx...
'onDone':function(file,data,response){
$('#uitabs-2').append('DONE');
$('#uitabs').tabs('option','active',$('uitabs-').index());
}
</script>
```

then I need a code when 'onDone' function do and jump to #uitabs-2

```
$('#uitabs').tabs('option','active',$('uitabs-').index());}
```

I tried this line code but jumped to #uitabs-3

and solution can I using class/ID/or name?

thanks!

Comment: you lost me on the script inside uitabs part.. can you provide the full code of what that script is?

Comment: if you do a jsfiddle that would help a lot too..

Comment: okay i fix it manully.:)

Answer (score 0):

here's solution

```
$('#uitabs').tabs('option','active',1);
```